Got AttributeError when creating an app with dash
I am a beginner on Dash, working on Anaconda notebook. As I tried a very simple app, I got an error at line 3 creation of an app object with an AttributeError maybe linked to a wrong Flask version. Please see my screenshot. Can anybody kindly help me?
I am using Flask 3.0.3 in my conda environement and cannot load 3 1.0.
